# How can I display the version of my sitepackage in the frontend?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to display the version of my `sitepackage` (from my declaration file `ext_emconf.php` ) in the frontend.

**How do I query this information**? I was thinking of using a `DataProcessor` in my `FLUIDTEMPLATE`, but I’m not sure whether I need to write my own or if there’s already one I can use for that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your exact needs you could make use of `ExtensionManagementUtility::getExtensionVersion()` to inject a global TypoScript constant via `ExtensionManagementUtility::addTypoScriptConstants()`:

```php
// ext_localconf.php
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTypoScriptConstants(sprintf(
    'site.version = %s',
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getExtensionVersion('sitepackage')
));
```

Afterwards you can use this constant anywhere in TypoScript setup including `variables` of Fluid templates:

```
// TypoScript setup
10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
10 {
  // ...
  variables {
    siteVersion = {$site.version}
  }
}
```

Now use this variable anywhere you like in your template:

```html
<!-- Fluid template -->
<p>Site {siteVersion}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no DataProcessor for that.

I'd suggest to create a small PHP class to read out the version and integrate it via TypoScript as a USER object.

```php
namespace Vendor\Sitepackage\Service;

class SitepackageVersionService
{

    public function getVersion(): string
    {
        $version = '';
        $packageManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Package\PackageManager::class);
        $extensionKey = 'my_extension_key';
        if ($packageManager->isPackageActive($extensionKey)) {
            $package = $packageManager->getPackage($extensionKey);
            $version = $package->getPackageMetaData()->getVersion();
        }

        return $version;
    }

}
```

```
page.10.variables.sitePackageVersion = USER
page.10.variables.sitePackageVersion.userFunc = Vendor\Sitepackage\Service\SitepackageVersionService->getVersion
```

```html
<strong>Version: {sitePackageVersion}</strong>
```

Comment: I'd suggest to also use `ExtensionManagementUtility::getExtensionVersion()` here since it already catches a lot of possible issues.

Comment: Didn't know that function, nice!